# reading file name gets deleted

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have an script that reads the file and compare the string by a pattern, if it returns false it will delete the line on the .txt file.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const lineReplace = require('line-replace')
const fs = require('fs');
const inputFileName = './outputfinal.txt';

const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(inputFileName),
});

let testResults = [];
readInterface.on('line', line => {
    testResult = test(line);
    console.log(`Test result (line #${testResults.length+1}): `, testResult);
    testResults.push({ input: line, testResult } );
    if (testResult == false){
        console.log(`Line #${testResults.length} will get deleted from this list`);
        lineReplace({
          file: './outputfinal.txt',
          line: testResults.length,
          text: '',
          addNewLine: false,
          callback: onReplace   
        });

        function onReplace({file, line, text, replacedText}) {

        };
    };
});

// You can do whatever with the test results here.
//readInterface.on('close', () => {
//    console.log("Test results:", testResults);
//});

function test(str){

    let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; // email regex

    str = str.split(","); 

    // string should be of length 3 with str[1] number of length 7
    if(str && str.length === 3 && Number(str[1]) && str[1] ) {

        let temp = str[0].split("-");

        // check for 85aecb80-ac00-40e3-813c-5ad62ee93f42 separately.
        if(temp && temp.length === 5 &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{8}/.test(temp[0]) &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{4}/.test(temp[1]) &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{4}/.test(temp[2]) &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{4}/.test(temp[3]) &&  /[a-zA-Z\d]{12}/.test(temp[4])){

            // email regex
            if(regex.test(str[2])) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else { 
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know why my "outputfinal.txt" gets deleted. And it throws and error "No such file or directory" but the file was there and then removed.

Any help on this? Thank you

Comment: you're reading the file, and while reading every line you use the line-replace module to modify the file that you are still reading ... that is bound to cause trouble

Comment: the fact that lineReplace is asynchronous, and you carry on without waiting for it to finish only causes further problems

Comment: and how I solve this?

Comment: personally, I'd read the file and output only the lines I wanted to a new file, then delete the old file and rename the new file to the old file

Comment: but how? I still I doesn undestand how to do it to make it right, my script not works